# Did Appayya Dikshita accept the Nayanars?

Tags: history, shaivism, nayanar, appayya-dikshitar

Did Appayya Dikshita accept the Nayanars ?

Adi Shankaracharya did accept Kannappa Nayanar.
But What about Appayya Dikshita?

Comment: Can you please cite the reference where Adi Shankaracharya has accepted Kannappa Nayanar!.